# How can you prove that $\frac{a(a^2+2)}{3}$ is always an integer

Tags: number-theory

Where a is a non zero integer. I tried but I wasn't able to factor that 3 out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $3\mid a$ we are done, if not either $a = 1 \pmod 3$ or $a = 2 \pmod 3$, either case $a^2+2 = 0 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 4):

You can write the numerator as

> $$a^3-a\mod 3.$$

Fermat's little theorem says all $a$ are congruent to $a^3$ mod $3$, hence the numerator is divisible by $3$.

Comment: $a^3-a=(a-1)a(a+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Just discuss the situation $a=3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$

Comment: I see your point. These situations are from the Division Algorithm, since $0\leq r \lt b$, right?